# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android.graphics.Bitmap$Config.nativeToConfig on Samsung devices

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, hardware-acceleration

Reproduced with android:hardwareAccelerated="true" flag only on some samsung devices e.g. galaxy s4. Cannot reproduce on nexus4, nexus5, motorola razr and emulator. Crashed sometimes on big horizontal scroll view with listview inside. No my code in stacktrace, only android.view.* and android.graphics.*

Logcat:

```
6-15 09:10:24.570: W/dalvikvm(7993): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41856ac8)
06-15 09:10:24.570: W/System.err(7993): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=48
06-15 09:10:24.570: W/System.err(7993):     at android.graphics.Bitmap$Config.nativeToConfig(Bitmap.java:378)
06-15 09:10:24.570: W/System.err(7993):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig(Bitmap.java:1037)
06-15 09:10:24.570: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.setupModifiers(GLES20Canvas.java:1347)
06-15 09:10:24.570: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawBitmap(GLES20Canvas.java:791)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:118)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:399)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1008)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14180)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13118)
06-15 09:10:24.580: W/System.err(7993):     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13162)
...
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet on where you are getting this error? it would be easy to understand and come up with a solution

Comment: @amalan-dhananjayan, thanks for responding. I've updated android on this device from `4.2` to `4.4` and this issue disappeared. Also, code in this class changed, so I can't find now revision with this issue. I assume that it was a bug in custom samsung android build at version 4.2.